# Are the "My name is Pitt / My name is Paul" rhymes in Pulp Fiction a real-world reference?

Tags: pulp-fiction

In the movie Pulp Fiction, two separate characters at two separate times make first-name based rhymes.

The [first time](https://youtu.be/SLQpoBZygx4?t=57s), Jules says:

> My name's **Pitt**, and your ass ain't talking your way out of this **shit**.

The [second time](https://youtu.be/BEdUuuKYZ4k?t=3m52s), the bartender says:

> My name is **Paul**, and this shit is between **y'all**.

Jules is not named Pitt, and according to IMDB, in the script, [the bartender's name is English Bob](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110912/trivia?item=tr0791371).

Is there a real-world reference or reason for both of these characters to make rhyming first-name comebacks?

Comment: I'm really curious about the "Pitt" myself. I'm guessing it's just an alias he uses on this job much like the assigned color names in Reservoir Dogs?

Answer (score 6):

One reason is Tarantino like rhymes. Thanks to [non sequitur](http://arvind.typepad.com/devils_workshop/2009/05/quintessential_.html) for collecting theseTarantino rhymes:

> My name's Paul, 
>   and this is between y'all (Paul, the bartender in Pulp Fiction)
>
> My name's Pitt, 
>   and you ain't talkin' your ass outta this shit. (Jules in Pulp Fiction)
>
> My name is Buck, 
>   and I'm here to fuck. (Buck in Kill Bill)
>
> Zed’s dead baby, 
>   Zed’s dead. (Butch in Pulp Fiction)
>
> Kill Bill (The title of the movie rhymes)
>
> If your hand ain't off that case, 
>   I'm gonna unload right in your fuckin' face.(Pumpkin in Pulp Fiction)
>
> Somebody with a grudge blew Beaumont's brains out. Oh shit, that shit rhymes! "Blew Beau-mont's, brains out!" (Ordell in Jackie Brown)

As pointed out on [Movie Mistakes](https://www.moviemistakes.com/film1025/questions/pageall). The person who is asks Jules is named Brad before Jules says his name is Pitt; so perhaps this is also a joke... Brad Pitt.

Comment: His name is Brett, not Brad.

Answer (score -5):

It’s actually a lot simpler than you guys are making it seem.

Jules says “My name’s PIT”...as in Brett is stuck in a PIT (a metaphor for being in trouble) and he can’t talk his way out of it

Comment: Got any evidence for that that you could [edit] in? As shown by the other answer, it seems much more likely this is an artistic choice by Tarantino than a pit metaphor.

Comment: The rhyme is funny, but the metaphor is the real joke - if you can’t see it it’s because you’re not looking. Tarantino did similar stuff in most of his films.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the actual question, which is whether the rhymes are a real-world reference to anything.

Comment: This also fails to explain the "Paul" one.